# How should this MySQL Query look like?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following design:

```
ID    OPT_1    OPT_2    OPT_3    A_ID

1     3        4        3        1
2     5        2        1        1
3     1        2        2        1
```

I want to select all OPT's for A_ID 1, but when I run the query, I don't know the A_ID, I only know the OPT's.

So how can I insert a variable to get A_ID for the options I want?
for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ((OPT_1 = 1 OR OPT_1 = 5) 
   AND (OPT_2 = 4 OR OPT_2 = 2) 
   AND (OPT_3 = 3 OR OPT_3 = 2) 
   AND A_ID = $X=$X)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like you want a 'find ones that look like this' type query?

Comment: Not sure, I need the A_ID to be unique for all the OPT's I input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly best way to do it is to split it up a bit.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE A_ID in (
    SELECT A_ID
    FROM table 
    WHERE (OPT_1 = 1 OR OPT_1 = 5)
    union
    SELECT A_ID
    FROM table 
    WHERE (OPT_2 = 4 OR OPT_2 = 2)
)
```